# GPU libraries for integer matmul | overflow tolerated

Tags: matrix, blas, dense-matrix, fixed-point

Are there any high performance integer BLAS libraries that implement matrix multiplication i.e. i32gemm and i64gemm ? I need to use them for a cryptographic application and can tolerate overflows, i.e. I don't require the kernel to do any wraparound checks.

The difference between a Igemm and an Fgemm is that the latter retains the higher order bits and the previous retains the lower-order ones. My application would be performing computations on ciphers and not on the actual data. Since the data is selected in such a way that none of the elements of the product matrix (which are all signed) need more than 32 bits, the application can tolerate overflows on the ciphers.

Answer (score -1):

I think [cuBLAS](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas) and [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) are the libraries you are looking for.

Comment: The difference between a Igemm and an Fgemm is that the latter retains the higher order bits and the previous retains the lower-order ones. My application requires the lower-order bits only. I've given more context in the question.

Comment: NVIDIA claims that cuBLAS supports **half-precision (FP16) and integer (INT8) matrix multiplication operations**. I think it is worth exploring the library. If it does not provide explicit functionality for igemm, you can develop customised subroutines for igemm following their source code.

Comment: Yes, but I need more than 8 bits to represent the data and FP16 is already out of question ;).